# Display attribute image but if file_exists returns always false

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I can't get this working.

```
$filename = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL) . "media/wysiwyg/Logos/$manufacturerName.png";
$filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);
 if (file_exists($filename)) {

     echo "The file $filename exists";
 } else {
     echo "<img src='$filename' title='$manufacturerName' alt='$manufacturerName' style='float:right;margin:0px' />";
 }
```

I've tried many ways but it always returns false even thou it the image shows for the not existing echo.

What I'm I doing wrong? Safe mode is off, the files have permissions and the image actually show but in the false echo.

**EDIT:**

I'm doing it this way now with a new tag I learned about i.e. `<object data=`. I get a 404 error on using it but no php errors. It works good other than the 404s.

```
  <?php
        $_product = $this->getProduct();
        $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        $manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer(); 
        $filename = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . "/wysiwyg/Logos/$manufacturerName.png";
        if (empty($filename)) $filename = ''; ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getManufacturer()):?>
        <?php $manufacturerlogo = str_replace(" ", "_", $manufacturerName); ?>
        <?php if (file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . "/wysiwyg/Logos/$manufacturerlogo.png")): ?>
        <?php $size = getimagesize(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . "/wysiwyg/Logos/$manufacturerlogo.png");
        list($width, $height) = $size;
        $cleanfilename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($cleanfilename);
        ?>
    <?php endif ?>
        <object data="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL); ?><?php echo 'media/wysiwyg/Logos/'; ?><?php echo $manufacturerlogo; ?><?php echo $this->__('.png"') ?> <?php echo "title='$manufacturerName' alt='$manufacturerName' style='float:right;margin:10px;width:{$width}px;height:{$height}px'"; ?>" type="image/png"></object> 
    <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon file_exists only work with path and not with URLs that's why your function always displays the image.

Try using `Mage::getBaseDir('media')` to generate your image path instead.

Comment: Ill try this out but I might have not stated this to clear. The image exists, but where it's suppose to echo "image exists" it doesn't, even thou the image exist. So I have it echo(ing) where it's NOT suppose to exist :) It shows the image like this but then if the image really doesn't exist it shows a broken image. It's a little confusing the way I have it here.

Comment: Mage::getBaseDir('media') works as far showing when it's suppose to but it breaks the image like this: /home/xxxxx/public_html/media/wysiwyg/Logos/Lladró_Inc.png

Comment: Once you've ensured the image exists using the getBaseDir, you can use your original code to use in the src attribute of the img tag.